# Python if Statement Not Recognizing Variable Loaded From A Text File

Tags: python, variables, text

So I have a text file called Subject.txt with the contents "Fiction" (no quotations) inside it. One line, nothing else.

Using:

```
file = open("Subject.txt", "r")
Subject = (file.read())
file.close()
```

This writes the contents to a variable called Subject, which seems verified when I used

```
print(Subject)
```

and it returns Fiction as the response.

But this code...

```
if Subject == "Fiction":
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

...gets me the No response, not the Yes. If I were to manually create the variable the long way...

```
Subject = "Fiction"
if Subject == "Fiction":
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

...I get Yes.

But loaded from the text file, I don't. I need to create variables from text files, if possible, and I was trying to test that I got it right. I'm missing something.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are missing whitespace chracters `print("~~~~" + open("Subject.txt").read() + "~~~~")` ... - most probably your `if Subject == "Fiction\n":`  would be true

Comment: The line loaded from the text file likely ends with a newline character - print its `repr()` to see exactly what it contains.  Applying `.rstrip()` to the variable would be one solution.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably reading a newline character (`\n`) at the end of the file and it is being saved to your variable...

In order to get rid of this character, use the .strip method, which removes all space characters (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc..) in front and after a string. Your code should look like this

```py
file = open("Subject.txt", "r")
Subject = file.read().strip()
file.close()
```